# How to apply the "rounded-circle" in css? border-radius:50% not works

Tags: css

Apparently it seems easy, I use Bootstrap and in fact I am applying the "`rounded-circle`" class but nothing happens. basically to make the effect that the image becomes a circle the attribute is used: `border-radius: 50%! important;` But I don't know why it doesn't apply correctly.

```css
img{
border-radius:50%;
width:300px;
height:300px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://luisjordan.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/logo-ionic.jpg">
```

Comment: The border radius gets applied just fine in your example? But obviously a white image over a white background is not going to show any difference.

Comment: what can I do it to see any?

Comment: set border... border: 1px solid black; will show you that it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply try an image with a dark background or simply add a border to see how round the image with a white background

```css
img{
  border-radius:50%;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://csform.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Ionic-App-Dark-UI.jpg">

<img src="https://luisjordan.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/logo-ionic.jpg">
```